# Accessing from parent object a method from a script component located on a child

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've got an object player on which I've put a child which contains only a script casting a line to detect if the player is grounded. I'd like to get the result of this linecast in my playerControls script (component of player). To do this i've made a public methods that returns the result of the linecast, but I don't know how to make a reference to the script to call the method.

How can I do ?

Comment: `.GetComponent` ... look it up on the docs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.GetComponentsInChildren.html

```
 hingeJoints = GetComponentsInChildren<HingeJoint>();
```

If you only have one player you can also use a Singleton pattern. But the easier solution is to get the component of the child.

Comment: Arlight thank you, so writing down somthing like what follows would work ?

    myVariable = GetComponentInChildren<"MyScriptName">()

Comment: Without the quotation signs at MyScriptName and with a semi colon at the end yes.

Note that GetComponentInChildren returns one object while GetComponentsInChildren returns a list of objects. The difference is the one 's' in the method name.

Comment: @Doh09 `GetComponents` methods return an `array`, not a `List`.

Comment: More than one object nonetheless :-)

Comment: More than one element could mean an `array`, a `List`, a `Hashset`, an `IEnumerator`, etc. ;)

Comment: I am aware of that. Hence why I agreed and said that it at least was more than one object.